# Jira Gadget: Configuration isn't saved for reconfiguration

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-plugin, picker, jql

I am writing a gadget for Jira with some configuration options. One of these configuration options is a "project or filter picker".
My problem lies in the part, when I want to reconfigure the gadget's preferences. I have read the code of the timesince-gadget as an example and I think the relevant part is the following:

```
if (/^jql-/.test(gadget.getPref("projectOrFilterId"))){
    projectAndFilterPicker =
    {
        userpref: "projectOrFilterId",
        type: "hidden",
        value: gadgets.util.unescapeString(this.getPref("projectOrFilterId"))
    };
}  else {
    projectAndFilterPicker = AJS.gadget.fields.projectOrFilterPicker(gadget, "projectOrFilterId", args.options);
}
```

Basicly I've copied the code from the timesince-gadget. Unfortunately even if already configured, the javascript always enters the else part.
A problem is, that I ve no experience with jql and don't totally understand the if clause.

But usually (e.g. when calling the rest api and processing the config infos)

```
gadget.getPref("projectOrFilterId")
```

returns a string containing the id of the picked project or filter.

Question is now: How can I make my gadget remember the last configuration like it's done with some many other Jira gadgets?

I really hope anyone can help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turnes out, the answer is even simplier then I thought.
First: In the descriptor you can totally forget the if part from above. Just

```
var projectAndFilterPicker = AJS.gadget.fields.projectOrFilterPicker(gadget, "projectOrFilterId", args.options);
```

is needed.
Second: Retrieve the project's or filter's name in your rest resource, which shouldn't be a problem, since you already want to use the processed id. Then return this name back to the view part of your javascript and type in something like

```
this.projectOrFilterName = args.myrestclasskey.projectOrFilterName;
```

And tada: reconfiguration will display the old configured name!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once when I forgot to specify the option in the Gadget XML file. I solved it by adding this to the XML:

```
    <UserPref name="projectOrFilterId" datatype="hidden"/>
```

Comment: Since the getPref call returned the right value, I could have hardly forgotten the userPref. But thanks anyway!